# Is it possible to have a custom field in Inventory Detail subrecord on Item Receipt? NETSUITE

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Just like expiration date on inventory number subrecord on Item Receipt, can we have a custom field for manufacturing date in inventory number subrecord. Is there any feature need to be enabled? Does NetSuite have any functionality of Production/Manufacturing date? or any way to create a custom field in inventory number subrecord that is visible in IR subrecord?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, it is not possible to add a custom field to the inventory detail subrecord. Checking the CUSTOMISATION > LIST, RECORDS & FIELDS NS menu (using the administrator role), this sub-record is not available. I have, however, in the past re-created the subrecord using a Suitelet and a saved search which auto-populates the item lines with additional columns. Perhaps this route is a potential solution for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently encountered this in an implementation. We were requested to add the  Gross Weight and Net Weight fields in the Inventory Details window.

We used a SuiteApp called Lot Auto Number (Answer  ID: 100706).